# I can't understand how the code below continue looping through items in database?

Tags: php, authentication, while-loop

I want to check the user login entry data to find if they are existed.
Imagine we have just 10 records in the database(10 user).
I know if i want to check user login entry data with data in database, i should use while loop.
As you see in the code below i used while loop and fetch_assoc method to get each record from database.

**the code below works correct!**

but I can't understand the work flow of "**if statement**" inside the loop.

take the first record in database.
fetch_assoc method fetch the first record from the database to check it with user entry data. then "if statement" check both user data and fetched data with each other. what confuses me is that if data does not match with first record, else statement must return the user to login page. I mean just one row is checked!!
**-how does it check other records with user entry data!**

**-how does it jump from else statement to while loop!?**

could you please explain entire the code in detail.

```
    $select_query= "select `username`,`pass` from `register`";
    $result= $db_connection->query($select_query);

        while($row= $result->fetch_assoc()){
            if($row["username"] === $username && $row["pass"] === $pass){
                header("location:../account.php");
            }else{
                header("location:../login.php");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps create a query that will check for the username and password using for example a where clause instead of looping.

Comment: This is wrong logic, redirect to login should be set right after while loop. So the logic will be to check each record and if you found match you redirect to account. After running through all records no matches, you redirect to login.

Comment: Show what your ‘$db_connection->query()’ method does

Comment: Think for a sec about a problem. You have to check user login data? When? When user log in? Then you have single user so, no loop. Sometimes, from some unknown reason you have to check more of them (I have no idea how and why) but whom you redirect? I never sow situation where you can check user data in a bulk? Like system admin or something???? ' Iknow if i want to check user login entry data with data in database, i should use while loop.' - who told you that?

Answer (score 0):

I do beleive you want to check single user.

- 'I want to check the user login entry data to find if they are existed.' - well I am not familiar with your app logic but to check if some user exist you simply fetch from db with some parameters. And get single user if exist or empty row otherwise. Right?
- 'I know if i want to check user login entry data with data in database, i should use while loop.' - How? Who told you that. You need loop like that if you fetch many of them and do something with the data eg. list them?
- If you really have some scenario where you have to fetch all users and check something like you wrote above in code do not redirect there, save some data in array like $array['passed'] and $array['failed'] and then write another logic to redirect if needed.
- Redirect multiple times inside loop, is not possible, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

```
$select_query = "select `username`,`pass` from `register`"; // Fetching ALL user accounts from register table
$result= $db_connection->query($select_query); // Execute query

// Loop through all rows of query
while($row= $result->fetch_assoc()){ 

    // If username and password matches the user's input, then set HTTP Response header to do a 302 Redirect to ../account.php
    if($row["username"] === $username && $row["pass"] === $pass){
        header("location:../account.php");
    }

    // If username and password doesn't match the user's input, then set HTTP Response header to do a 302 Redirect to ../login.php
    else{
        header("location:../login.php");
    }
}
```

The code has a logical error whereby let's imagine your 'register' table is something like this:

```
username    |   pass
--------------------------
user1       |   password1
user2       |   password2
user3       |   password3
user4       |   password4
```

If the user entered correctly $username="user3" $pass="password3", the code will still output header("location:../login.php") because it is looping from the first row all the way to the end of the table (i.e. when the loop reaches the last row "user4" it will process the 'else' statment).

Better to update your code to something like this (assuming you are using php mysqli class):

```
session_start();

$select_query = " select `pass` from `register` where `username` = '".$db_connection->real_escape_string($username)."' "; 
$result = $db_connection->query($select_query); // Execute query

$redirectPage = '../login.php';
if( $result->num_rows == 1 ) {
    $dbPass = $result->fetch_object();

    if( $pass == $dbPass->pass ) {

        $redirectPage = '../account.php';

        $_SESSION['loginSuccess'] = true; // This let's account.php know that the user is properly authenticated

    }
}

header('Location: '.$redirectPage);
```